# position: fixed is not working in iOS when loading Angular site inside iframe in Ionic 3

Tags: ios, css, angular, ionic-framework, iframe

**Brief Description on what we are trying to achieve**

We are developing an **Angular** application. We developed it for both Web and Mobile using same code base. Mobile version contains lot of features such as **Push Notifications**, **SMS Subscriptions** etc. We are hoping to publish mobile version to App store and Play store. We are using simple Ionic 3 app to build it to Android and iOS.

Ionic 3 application contains only one page in which we are loading our **Angular Web Site** inside an **`iframe`**.

**HTML of Ionic page**

```
<ion-content>
  <iframe class= 'webPage' [src]="iframeSrc" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
  </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

**TS of Ionic page**

```
export class HomePage {
  iframeSrc: any;

  sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
  url: string = 'https://angular-load-ionic-iframe.stackblitz.io';

  constructor( sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
    this.iframeSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

  }
}
```

**Find [The Github Repository](https://github.com/sudarshanadayananda/angular-app-builder-ionic3) of Ionic 3 app [Here](https://github.com/sudarshanadayananda/angular-app-builder-ionic3).**

**I have created [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) Angular project which similar to My Angular application. Find it [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-load-ionic-iframe).**

> **My Issue**
>
> In my application, `app-header` and `app-footer` need to be fixed to
>   ViewPort and other content should be able to scroll. I successfully
>   achieved this for Android **But in iOS, `app-header` and `app-footer`
>   are not fixed to ViewPort and those are scrolling with other content
>   when I load my Angular application inside an `iframe` in Ionic app.**

**header.component.html**

```
<header>
  <div class="main">
        <h3>Countries</h3>
    </div>
</header>
```

**header.component.css**

```
.main {
    background-color: #46454A;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    padding:5px 50px;
}

header{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**footer.component.html**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <h3>This is footer</h3>
</footer>
```

**footer.component.css**

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  background-color:#47454b;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  padding:0px 50px;
}
```

I couldn't figure out **Is it `CSS` issue with iOS** or **Is it occurred as I load angular web site inside `iframe`**. Struggling for one day but still no success. If anyone can help me to fix this issue highly appreciated and If someone need more details about this feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this css in your style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  padding:0px 50px;
}
my-app{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

app-header,app-home,app-footer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
app-header,app-footer{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
   background-color:#47454b;
}
app-header{
  top:0;
}
app-footer{
  bottom:0;
}
app-home {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

remove all css of `header.component.css` and `footer.component.css`

here is stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-load-ionic-iframe-knkgq4?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give a try.

Comment: @Imon Thanks a ton. your answer is working like a charm. you save my life.

Comment: This is not even an answer. It's a "Here, let me do your work for you without explanation."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting the entire app mode / platform style to `md` via the app config? If you are able to solve this problem on Android then perhaps adopting Android styles globally for the iOS version will solve it for that platform too?

```
// app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      mode: 'md'
    }),  
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solutions. But it did not fix my issue. I cannot imagine that this issue occurred as I am loading Angular site inside `iframe`. But when I debug my iOS app in safari it shows that all the required styles are applied. Any way thanks for your effort.

Comment: No problem, worth a try, this is a fairly unusual setup so I think you will have trouble getting help on this issue.

Comment: Yes this is actually unusual. I am already spent one day on this. but could not find a solution yet. Any way thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with ionic and your angular setup but: there is a similar position fixed bug in safari Browsers.

The problem is: you cant position fixed Elements  that are direct Children of the body tag.

The solution is: wrapping the content in another div. And putting every inside it.

Maybe you can try to put your Header and footer element inside an extra div so the footer isnt a direct child of the body tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, It is not the case. problem is with `iframe`. without `iframe` all the styles are applied in iPhone as I needed

Answer (score 1):

Not tried, but worth a try:

style.css

```
body {
margin: 0px;
position: sticky;
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
```

}

home.component.html

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let country of countries">
        <div class="code"><strong>Code:</strong> {{country.countryCode}}</div>
        <div class="name"><strong>Name:</strong> {{country.countryName}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

footer.component.css

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  background-color:#47454b;
  z-index:99;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  padding:0px 50px;
}
```

I had similar issues in IE with sticky footer and header, this does the trick for me. You said that you are using iframes, but could not find some in your fork, only div-wrapped content... if you include the iframe, you can try to apply a relative positioning for the iframe like

```
position: relative;
```

to avoid collision with the header and footer. Hope this helps.